# Alternative ways to insulate a shallow slab foundation?

Tags: insulation, floor, foundation

I would like to turn a shed on a shallow slab foundation into a living space for a family member. Insulating the roof and walls seems straight forward enough, but the floor and foundation are tricky.

I considered insulating the foundation by digging around and inserting insulation, but one side of the foundation is blocked by a recently added patio and is not accessible. I was wondering what alternatives I may have to frost protecting and insulating this floor/foundation?

Comment: Sounds like doing this could potentially result in the need to replace the slab.  If it were me I would work with what I've got - like @Ecnerwal says in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can either build up (put an insulated floor **on top of** the concrete slab floor - most people would also see this as nicer than a concrete slab floor for living in) or you can waste a lot of heat (and the floor will always feel cold.)